# UIImage? is not identical to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimage

i am trying to store 3 image in an array then display them in a ScrollView but it's showing this error in this line :              "self.paginatedScrollView?.images = images"

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        displayPost(post)

        paginatedScrollView = PaginatedScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))
        self.view.addSubview(paginatedScrollView!) // add to the

        let images = [ post!.image1.value,  post!.image2.value, post!.image3.value]

        self.paginatedScrollView?.images = images
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because UIImage? is an optional. You just need to **unwrap the value of images before assigning them by using ! operator**.

Try this:

```
let images: [UIImage] = [ (post!.image1.value)!,  (post!.image2.value)!, (post!.image3.value)!]
```

Edit: The array you created earlier was saving optionals. So I just unwrapped all values that you were saving in the array by adding a '!'. Read about optionals here: http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/swift-optionals-use-let/

Comment: This means that the array is storing optionals.. Specify the type of array explicitly and make sure you save unwrapped values in the array.

Comment: oh that fixed the problem ! thank you can you explain what did you do please !